# Points on an Arc using D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have drawn a few concentric arcs on my SVG following the code below :-

```
var width = 2000;
var height = 500;



var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width",width)
        .attr("height",height);

var group = canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(100,200)");


var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(function(d){return (d-1)})
        .outerRadius(function(d){return d})
        .startAngle(1)
        .endAngle(p/2);

var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(orbitRadius)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","arc");

    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d",arc);
```

Here orbitRadius array holds the radius for each arc.

Now I want to find out "n" points (x and y co-ordinate) on each arc which are at the same height on each of the arcs. The four points on an arc can be equi-distant. That is, say p1,p2,p3,p4 are 4 points or arc 1, and q1,q2,q3,q4 are 4 points on arc 2, then p1 and q1 are at same height (w.r.t the SVG), p2 and q2 are at same height so on and so forth.

Please help.

Edit :- Please find the image of what I am trying to achieve :-
at https://www.dropbox.com/s/w87118tphnmya7a/image.PNG

Comment: I think it would help a lot if you could provide some kind of diagram that shows what you are trying to accomplish. Even if it's something crudely hand-drawn...

Comment: @jshanley please find the image here https://www.dropbox.com/s/w87118tphnmya7a/image.PNG

Comment: I'm assuming `orbitRadius` refers to an array of radii. What's `p`?

Comment: Ah, pi, as in half-circles i'm guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to use some trig to figure out where to place the points, but the logic shouldn't be all that difficult.

You know the radius of each arc, and presumably you know the heights (y-values) that each set of matching points should be at.

Have a look at this unit-circle diagram:

[image: unit circle]

In our case, instead of a unit circle, we have a known radius **R** which is the radius of the current arc, but the math works the same way.

The missing value that you need to find for each arc is **x**. To find that, we first need to find what the angle is. Here's where the trig comes in, good old SOH-CAH-TOA.

Given the right triangle as shown in the diagram, we know that:

**sin(theta) = y / R**

so to find the angle itself, we can just take the inverse sine, or arcsin:

**theta = asin(y / R)**

We also know that:

**cos(theta) = x / R**

So putting those together, we get:

**cos(asin(y / R)) = x / R**

solve for x:

**x = cos(asin(y / R)) * R**

We can then use this to create a function that, given a y-value and a radius, gives back the x-value:

```
function getPointX(y, radius) {
  return Math.cos(Math.asin(y/radius)) * radius;
}
```

Now that we have that all out of the way, on to the d3 part.

To plot your points you'll need to make an array of the values you wish to use for your heights, relative to the origin of your arcs. Remember that in SVG coordinates, higher values of **y** mean *lower* on your diagram. Therefore, distance below the origin is positive, and distance above it is negative. As an example:

```
var heights = [-70, -15, 20, 60];
```

Next I'm going to create a combined dataset.

```
var combinedData = orbitRadius.map(function(d) {
  return {
    r: d,
    heights: heights
  };
});
```

This creates an array of objects, where each object has a property `r` which is one of the radii from `orbitRadius` and each object also contains the array of `heights`.

There's a bit of unnecessary redundancy in having each object contain the same heights array, but it will make the drawing part simpler to do it this way.

To draw the points, I'll first make a group to contain the points on each separate arc:

```
var pointGroup = group.selectAll('.point-group')
  .data(combinedData)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr('class', 'point-group');
```

Here's the tricky part. I'll then use a nested selection to create a point at each separate height. For the `.data()`, we'll use a function of the data from the pointGroup selection, which returns only the array of heights. This means that the enter selection will contain one element for each separate height.

```
pointGroup.selectAll('.point')
  .data(function(d) {return d.heights;})
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'point')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return getPointX(d, this.parentNode.__data__.r);
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {return d;})
  .attr('r', 4);
```

The `cy` attribute is simply `d` since the heights data represents y-values. For the `cx` I'm calling the `getPointX()` function we made before, passing in the y-value, and the *parent node's* radius value, since the parent node is the group of all points sharing a radius.

Here's a working example as a [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/jiwiv/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: :- Thank you so much for this detailed answer. It works flawlessly. 
 
I am tyring to plot circles on the arcs ( in place of "points" ) as per my data set. My data set is :-
`var data = [["John","Internet",19],["John","Water",20],["Sam","Internet",36],["Sam","Water",44],["Charles","Internet",51],  ["Charles","Water",53],["Rob","Internet",39],["Rob","Water",30]]` and `var myColors = [d3.rgb(137,195,95),d3.rgb(241,137,108),d3.rgb(253,233,127),d3.rgb(109,151,216)];`;
The radius of each circle should be from data[2] value and the color should be myColors[i]. 
Can you please help.

Comment: i modified the combinedData and added planetRadius (array which contains all the data[2] elements from my data set ). But I am not able to use these values as radius of the circles. Please help

Comment: How are you determining the arc-radius with that dataset? The circle radius can be set as a function of the data `circle.attr('r', function(d) { return d[2]; })` in the first case or `circle.attr('r', function(d) { return d.planetRadius; })` in the second case.

Comment: My code
`var planetRadius = new Array();
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
 planetRadius[i] = data[i][2];
}`
and `var combinedData = orbitRadius.map(function(d) {
    return {
    r: d,
    heights: heights,
    planetRadius: planetRadius
  };
});`
But when I do 
`pointGroup.selectAll('.point')
  .data(function(d) {return d.heights;})
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'point')
.attr('cx', function(d) {
  return getPointX(d, this.parentNode.__data__.r);
})
.attr('cy', function(d) {return d;})
.attr('r', function(d){return d.planetRadius ;});`
the circles dont appear on the arcs.
Plz Help.